# How to use the public variables in parent to child?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I am trying to access the variables in a parent class from its child, but I don't know how to use it.

The parent class is `ATempSensor`:

```
public abstract class ATempSensor {  // abstract=can have children inherit
                                    //  from this class, but no instantiation.
    static String cmd ;        // command to send to shell.
    static String cmd_result ; // Line returned by command.
    static int    cmd_number ; // if command just returned a number, here it is. 

    public void runCmd() {
        try {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); // get runtime shell.
            Process pr = run.exec(cmd);         // start command.
            pr.waitFor() ;                       // wait for command to finish.       
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader  // get output from command.
            ( new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream() ) );
            cmd_result = buf.readLine();
            cmd_number = Integer.parseInt(cmd_result);
        }
        catch (Exception e ) { // can get exceptions for exec, waitfor, parseInt
        }
    }
}
```

The child class is `SwitchTempSensor`:

```
package tempsensor ;                    // added to define membership of package.
import java.io.* ;

public class SwitchTempSensor extends ATempSensor{
    //--- class member data (variables) are called fields.

    static String cmd= "ousb io portb ";
    runCmd()
}
```

Both java files are in the same directory called "tempsensor", Mymain.java is outside tempsensor.
Directory look like-

```
Mymain.java
    |           
tempsensor       
    |----------SwitchTempSensor.java
    |----------ATempSensor.java
```

In the child class, I am trying to use the string called `cmd`. I have used by redeclaring `static String`, it is necessary? I also want to use the `runCmd()` in child. If I use runCmd() in my child class, I got error saying "error: invalid method declaration; return type required".

What is the proper way to use variable and class in child class (`SwitchTempSensor`)?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from using `runCmd()` in the child class, but it sounds like you want the parent class to use the child class's variables as though they were overrides, not the other way round as stated in your question. However there is no variable overriding in Java. Possibly the `cmd` and other variables should be instance variables initialized by the constructor? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If I use runCmd() in my child class, I got error saying "error: invalid method declaration; return type required".

Comment: So you got a compilation error? You're expected to be able to fix those yourself. You haven't actually clarified your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. But I think what you need is a constructor in the `SwitchTempSensor` class.

First things first, it is not necessary to declare `cmd` again. That's the whole point of inheritance!

In the class scope, you can't call methods, so you can't do something like this:

```
class SwitchTempSensor {
    runCmd();
}
```

Method calls must be contained in methods. So delete the "redeclaration" of `cmd` in `SwitchTempSensor` and also the `runCmd()` call.

You must put the method call and the variable initialization in a method or a constructor. If you put it in the constructor, the variable will be initialized when a `SwitchTempSensor` object is created:

```
public SwitchTempSensor() {
    cmd = "ousb io portb ";
    runCmd();
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
new SwitchTempSensor();
```

You can also put it in a method:

```
public void someMethod() {
    cmd = "ousb io portb ";
    runCmd();
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
SwitchTempSensor sensor = new SwitchTempSensor();
sensor.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to access a value in your child class from a method in the parent class. That simply won't work. Instead, if the implementation truly is abstract, you can have the child class expose the value through an overridden method that the parent class knows about:

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class ATempSensor {

    abstract public String getCommand();

    public void runCmd() {

        try {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(getCommand());
            pr.waitFor() ;

            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader
            ( new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream() ) );

            String cmd_result = buf.readLine();
            int cmd_number = Integer.parseInt(cmd_result);
        }
        catch (Exception e ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

`SwitchTempSensor`:

```
public class SwitchTempSensor extends ATempSensor {

    @Override
    public String getCommand() {
        return "ousb io portb";
    }
}
```

In your `MyMain` class, when you call `runCmd` on an instance of `SwitchTypeSensor`, it will call the method declared within the parent class, using the command string defined within `SwitchTypeSensor`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, if no access modifier is applied to a variable, the default access modifier used by java is package-private, not `public`. You have to explicitly specify `public` before variable declaration like:

```
public static String cmd ;
```

Secondly, redeclaring is not required. You may use it directly as:

```
cmd = "value";
```

or

`super.cmd = "value";`

This is valid for both default and `public` access modifiers.

And best way to access a variable in inherited class is to declare that variable as `protected`. This way it will be accessible in inherited class only.

Comment: `default` is a keyword in the `switch` statement, not an access modifier. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: if I use cmd="value";  when I complie it gave me error " <identifier> expected".

Answer (score 0):

Just call `super.cmd` in order to reference the variable. For example `super.cmd = "some command"`. If you want to call the runCmd() method just type `super.runCmd()`
Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java by default if you do not specify any access modifier for a variable it is set as package-private.

To allow the child class to access their parent's variables you might be looking at setting them to `protected`.

Consider this example:

```
public class testChildren extends testParent {
    public testChildren() {
        System.out.println(super.test);
    }
}

public class testParent {
    protected String test = "apple";
}
```

When you instantiate the class `testChildren` using `testChildren test = new testChildren();`. The output is;

> apple

You might also be interested in the access modifier table noted in the Java documentation found **here:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

```
Access Levels
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public       Y         Y       Y          Y
protected    Y         Y       Y          N
no modifier  Y         Y       N          N
private      Y         N       N          N
```

Based on this table, obviously you can also make the variables accessible by using `public` but that is not advisable as it means that everyone would be able to modify it